# A variation of the Lady Tea Tasting problem

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution, randomized-tests

I am quite stuck on this question. My intuition would have been to say that we would prefer to pour milk first on heads, but I am not sure.

The setting is: the Lady guesses "milk first" in 2/3 of the cases and we have a coin that lands heads 2/3 of the time. Then for each of the 8 cups, you flip the coin and pour milk first or tea first depending on the outcome of the coin flip, would you prefer to pour milk first on heads or pour tea first on heads.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To do what? To guess what the Lady guesses, perhaps? Unclear. Like the actor asks, "What's my motive?"

Comment: I agree with @Carl.  I have considered offering an answer, but in framing it out I realized the experimental protocols are both (a) different from the original and (b) not completely or clearly set out (for instance, does the lady know you will be pouring randomly?), thereby making it unclear what the experiment is. I also saw that what constitutes significant evidence of the lady's prowess depends on the experiment, so I don't even know for sure what a "significant" result would be. Even the null hypothesis is unclear: does it make sense to test that the lady guesses 2/3s of the time?

Comment: Let me elaborate on that last point.  The lady in the original experiment knew the protocols and had an interest in performing well. This is effectively a two-person game in which we can find the optimal response for her, assuming she can't truly tell which liquid was poured first (and knows that). It is *not* optimal to guess milk two-thirds of the time: it is best, when she knows milk will be poured first with a chance of 2/3, to *always* guess milk. She can expect to get $8\times 2/3\approx 5$ correct answers and has a 4% chance of getting all 8 of them right.

Comment: BTW, although the original experiment was hypergeometric, this one is not: the Binomial distribution is the relevant one.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: *"she  states that she will choose at most six cups to be milk-first and at most six cups to be tea-first"* I don't follow this statement. Is this a stopping rule? After six cups of either type she stops tasting, or is it that after six cups she continues but will be wrong?

Comment: Which two mistakes does she make? If she already says that she is only selecting up to 6 cups then the error can be just due to that.

Comment: In the sense that she thinks any more than that is "far too unlikely to happen“ and then she actually makes two mistakes, by misclassifying.

Answer (score 1):

*Note, the question has been merged and the text has changed. This answer is the answer to the following version: [A modified Lady Tasting Tea problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565599/a-modified-lady-tasting-tea-problem)*

---

Let's say that a taster would completely randomly order the tea cups using a normal distribution and call cups that draw a positive figure milk first and a negative figure tea first. Except when there would be 6 of such category in which case we select only the outer 2 of the ordering. This would be the process of a taster that is completely unaware of the taste.

If the taster would not have the six cups rule then the probability of 2 mistakes would be binomial distributed. For each cup the taster independently selects correct or wrong with fifty-fifty probability.

But with the six limit there are cases when there are seven or eight cups of one kind. and the taster wrongly orders them automatically because of the six rule. You might think that this alters the probabilities in a similar fashion to the principle behind the geometric distribution where the probability is 1/70 to have everything correct instead of the binomial distribution all correct ${1}/{2^8}$.

Interestingly, it does't matter. The probability of two mistakes is still a binomial distribution.

We can have a similar experimental process where we have the taster first select the groups and then afterwards the experimenter randomly decides which cup is tea first or milk first (If the null hypothesis is correct, then it doesn't matter what happens first). **Because this experimental setup (deciding whether a cup is milk/tea first) happens with independent coin flips the probability of two mistakes will be according to a binomial distribution.**

---

I see now that you are considering the conditional situation:

"Then by chance only one of the cups is tea- first and seven of the cups are milk-first"

To compute this we have to count the ways that the taster can order the cups. But now, for this conditional case, the process of an unaware taster plays a role.

Above, the unaware taster uses a continuous random distribution to order the cups and select the two groups. But the number of cases where the groups with two/six distribution occur can differ depending on what the taster does when they encounter one/seven or zero/eight in the random draws from the normal distribution. Are they just selecting the two extremes, or are they repeating the random draws?

The differences in this process will change the probability for the taster to select a two/six combination. A different probability for the taster to select a two/six combination changes the probability for the taster to make two mistakes (the taster must select a two/six combination in order to be able to have only 2 mistakes if the reality is one/seven).

But let's ignore this for the moment and consider that the taster will flip coins for each cup and if there are 2 or less of one group, then they will randomly select from the other group to fill up. In this case the probability that the taster will have 2 tea-first cups and 6 milk-first cups is the probability that the coin flips ends with 0, 1 or 2 tea first. This probability is 37/256. Then the probability that the right tea-first cup is among those 2 selected tea-first cups is 1/4 and so the probability of only two mistakes is 37/1024.

Comment: Thank you for your help!