# A modified Lady Tasting Tea problem

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, randomized-tests

I don't really know how to approach the following problem.

We flip a fair coin for each of the eight cups and we pour milk into that cup first if the coin lands heads, else we pour tea first. Then by chance only one of the cups is tea- first and seven of the cups are milk-first. When the lady was told about the randomization mechanism, she states that she will choose at most six cups to be milk-first and at most six cups to be tea-first. If the lady makes two mistakes, what is the p-value for this hypothesis test?

Comment: Comments on [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565592/a-variation-of-the-lady-tea-tasting-problem) apply here too.  She has no reason to restrict her guesses: if she has any skill then it would reduce her expected success rate, and if she has none then it makes not difference.  Incidentally, from the detailed setup here, you can deduce that she cannot have said the single tea-first example was milk-first so must have made five milk-first guesses (all correct) and three tea-first guesses (one correct and two wrong)